# Under which circumstances does it make sense to lose track of where an exception was thrown from?

Tags: .net, programming-practices, exceptions, exception-handling

Is there any valid reason why a `catch` block on a lower layer would throw back an exception caused by a higher, unknown layer using the following syntax:

```
throw ex;
```

... rather than:

```
throw;
```

... ?

In the first case, not only the `catch` block doesn't deal with the exception, but it also reset its `StackTrace` property, making it more difficult to understand what caused it.

Why would anyone want a `catch` block in a lower layer to behave like this?

Comment: What do you mean by "caused by a higher layer?"  Like in a callback?

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt a callback, an event handler, an overriden method... pretty much anything that can execute code outside the assembly boundaries. The chain of methods originates from within the `try` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, having a `catch` block which only rethrows the exception is usually useless. But, the only real world scenario i can think of which makes sense to use `throw ex` instead of `throw` is if you're developing some sort of third party library which you by all means dont want anyone in the outter scope who's using your code to see the full stacktrace. Im not saying this is a good thing, but it might happen.

Comment: We agree that it's pointless to try and hide away this information when A) it's always possible to catch first-chance exceptions and B) the exception can still be caught from where it was first thrown?

Comment: It is just to reduce confusion. If the API writer knows where the exception comes from, they are reinterpreting it in a more "API friendly" way, so the API user does not have to wonder so much. Since you are wondering why anyone would do this, I doubt you are encountering this problem in a friendly library.

Comment: @FrankHileman I'm actually encountering this behavior with a 3rd party UI control library, which I won't name here. It catches exceptions thrown from event handlers then throws it back using `throw ex` syntax.